# Fluently map assemblies/entities at run time

Tags: nhibernate, reference, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Simple question for I bet a not so simple answer.

Think of a project like Wordpress. The base of Wordpress is great and the developers built it to be extended with widgets or plugins etc.

Now think NHibernate, specifically with Fluent Mappings.

Put them together and you have a great and stable "base" system BUT how do you load mappings presented from external assemblies? I realize that the system would have to load the Assemblies on the fly using reflection but how do you configure nHibernate, Fluently, at first run to realize that there are extra entities to be loaded from those assemblies? How do you reference them?

I know you can;t add Mappings at run-time after the configurations is made, well you have to recreate the SessionFactory. This is why I want to load all required entities at runtime.

I also know that this can be somewhat accomplished with Dependancy Injection but I do not wish to go that route nor want the extreme baggage that comes with it.

If the plain old nHiberante config file can be modified and then referenced at runtime to reflect new Entities I can only assume there has to be a way to do it Fluently.

Also, based on answers: do you make the configuration from the base project or a DATA ACCESS assembly?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "the extreme baggage that comes with it" May I ask what extreme baggage you refer to? Maybe I can help you understand IoC containers better.

Comment: I certainly would like to understand them better. Most of the documentation out there is sparse at best and is designed for software gurus, they just don;t get back to basics or leave out middle code that is needed. I would appreciate it. I did have a mess around with Castle before but it took me about two days to get it up and running, since the docs were incomplete, only to find I couldn't go any further using Castle with my intended project. I do get the jist of it and why it is mega useful but I fear for some projects it is overkill, yet if I understood it better I would think otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass an NHibernate Configuration object to `Fluently.Configure()`. That way you can update the configuration. You need to re-create the session factory when you do that, like you said.

You can scan the assemblies in the bin folder for assemblies that contain fluent mapping classes (`Assembly.Load`, then check

```
Assembly.GetExportedTypes()
        .Any(x => x.IsClass
               && !x.IsAbstract
               && typeof(IMappingProvider).IsAssignabledFrom(type))
```

or similar) and add the assembly. When all assemblies are scanned, (re-)create the session factory.

I'm doing something similar in an extensible application framework I have written (although I've moved to from Fluent NHibernate to NHibernate mapping by code, but the principles are similar).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "NHibernate mapping by code"? Is this something similar to Fluent?

Comment: NHibernate 3.2 comes with a built in way to map classes using code instead of XML/attributes and to automatically map classes by convention. Its purpose is similar to FluentNHibernate, the syntax is a bit different, however. I wouldn't say it's necessarily better, but I wanted to move to NH 3.2 and reduce the number of external dependencies. FNH is a bit behind NH and currently only supports NH 3.1 (officially). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777898/docs-examples-for-nhibernate-3-2-mapping-by-code

Comment: Great, I didn't realise that was there. I may look into it considering I am only starting with Fluent. I assume that my initial query can be accomplished in a similar way also as you mentioned above? Also is this meant to be done from the base project, web application in my case, or can it be done from an "in the middle" assembly, a data access assembly for instance.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I register all mappings during application startup (I'm mainly doing web apps). For larger projects I create a dedicated configuration project which contains everything related to - well - configuration: scanning assemblies for mappings, registering modules for the IoC container etc. But where you do this isn't all that important. As long as it is consistent and makes sense to you. Typically I'd somehow add this to the persistence/data access related part of the application.